# Can a Connect IQ widget get details for currently playing audio

Tags: garmin, monkeyc

Would it be possible to get the details like song title and album for audio currently playing on a Garmin smart watch, regardless of the service (Spotify, Amazon Music) that the user is listening with?

Comment: Stackoverflow is geared towards [computer programming-related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Are you programming a widget?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into the feasibility of creating a widget to track what music the user has listened with the ultimate goal of creating a Last.fm scrobbler for Garmin watches